# Is it possible to use one file for two or more directories with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I've an **index.php** file in my home directory and want to other subdirectories to use this file, too. So, when a user calls **example.com/subdirectory-1/** and **example.com/subdirectory-2/** he should see the content of **index.php** file of my home directory.

Is this possible with htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess in the document root ,add the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

This will rewrite all existent subdirectories to /index.php .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I didn't express myself correctly. I do not want to redirect all subdirectories to index.php file but only some of them. I need this for a multilingual site, so **example.com/en/** and **example.com/fr/** should use the same file but **example.com/images/** not. Is it possible to arrange this? Thank you.